# Validate if the user is present in AD Group under SharePoint Group using CSOM

Tags: development, active-directory, sharepoint-on-prem

I need to check if the user is a part of a specific SP group before performing some operations. The user can be a part of an "AD Group" which is under that "Sharepoint Group".

For Ex. 
User "U" can be a part of AD Group "AD_group" and that AD Group is directly present under SharePoint Group "SP_Group", we have created a method "CheckIfUserHasAccess", and it should return true if the user is found under AD Group and SP Group.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean that the “AD Group” is under the “SharePoint Group”?

You can check if the current user is in AD group or SharePoint group.

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

[How to find whether user is member of SharePoint group or active directory.](http://mehulpatel77.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-find-user-member-of-sharepoint.html#!/2014/05/how-to-find-user-member-of-sharepoint.html)

[Check if current user is member of a SharePoint group using JQuery.](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2017/10/check-if-current-user-is-member-of.html)

Comment: There could be AD groups inside Sharepoint Groups. The requirement was to check if the user is present in both SP Group and AD group.
For Eg : 
SP_Group Test
- User1
- User2
- AD1 (Which intrernally has 100 of users)

Comment: You could integrate the two solutions "check in AD group" and "check in SharePoint group", if they all return "true", then the user in both SP group and AD group.